# C - Assigning pointers to arrays? Based on four examples

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Assume following Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int arrayXYZ[10];
    int i;
    int *pi;
    int intVar;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        arrayXYZ[i] = i;
    }
    pi = arrayXYZ; // Reference 1
    pi++;          // Reference 2
    arrayXYZ++;    // Reference 3
    arrayXYZ = pi;  // Reference 4
}
```

- Reference 1 is correct: pi points to first element in arrayXYZ -> *pi = 0
- Reference 2 is correct: element to which pi points is incremented -> *pi = 1
- Reference 3 is not correct: **I am not completely sure why.** Every integer needs 4 bits of memory. Hence, we cannot increment the address of the head of the array by just one? Assume, we had a char array with sizeof(char)=1 -> Would the head of the array point to the next bucket?
- Reference 4 is not correct: **I am not completely sure why.** Why cannot the head of the array point to the address to which pi points?

Thanks for all clarifications!
I am a new member, so if my question doesn't follow the Stackoverflow guidelines, feel free to tell me how I can improve my next questions!

Comment: This didn't compile

Comment: An array is not a pointer. You cannot change the "value" of an array.

Comment: Yes of course, because References 3 + 4 are not correct. My question is why. @coderredoc

Comment: 3-4 is incorrect because those are not modifiable l-values.

Comment: @MichaelWalz right. But why cannot I change the address of an array -> see reference 3.
And isn't pi just the pointer to a particular address? arrayXYZ is also a pointer to the first element of the array. Let's assume pi points to the first bucket in the array. Why cannot I assign pi to arrayXYZ?

Comment: @AndrejCoding an array is an array. But it _can_ decay to the pointer to it's first element.

Comment: "arrayXYZ is also a pointer to the first element of the array." No it's not. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @coderredoc, so the answer is that just by definition I cannot change arrayXYZ? 
So I cannot write, e.g. arrayXYZ =  arrayXYZ + 4 to point to the next integer bucket?

Comment: @MichaelWalz alright! Got it. I should not think about the array as a pointer by definition.

Comment: @AndrejCoding -- arrays are not pointers in C; they are objects. Array identifiers _decay_ to pointers to the first element of an array in most expressions, and this causes no end of confusion when people are thinking that arrays are pointers. But actual arrays (not pointers) can neither be assigned to nor returned from functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arrayXYZ++;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
arrayXYZ += 1;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
arrayXYZ = arrayXYZ + 1;
```

This is not allowed because the C language does not allow it. An array can not be assigned to.

```
arrayXYZ = pi;
```

This fails for the same reason. An array can not be assigned to.

The other assignments work because you are allowed to assign to a pointer.

Also keep in mind that arrays and pointers are distinct datatypes. In C, there are circumstances where arrays decay into a pointer to their first element for convenience purposes. Which is why this works:

```
pi = arrayXYZ;
```

However, this is just an automatic conversion, so that you don't have to write:

```
pi = &arrayXYZ[0];
```

This automatic conversion does not mean that arrays are the same thing as pointers.

Answer (score 1):

From C11 standard §[6.3.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1) (N1570)

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially designates an object;64) if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. **A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const- qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const- qualified type.

And also From §[6.5.2.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.4)

> The operand of the postfix increment or decrement operator shall have atomic, qualified, or unqualified real or pointer type, and **shall be a modifiable lvalue**.

As pointed out here these are the reasons why those statements are illegal. Same way for assignment operation the left one has to be modifiable. Here it is not. That's why the problem.

Now to explain why the other two works - there is a thing called [array decay](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). Array in most situations (exceptions are when used in operand of `&`, `sizeof` etc) are converted to pointer to the first element of the array and that pointer is being assigned to the `pi`. This is modifiable. And that's why you can easily apply `++` over it.